# Find out real shell behind /bin/sh

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have a Red Hat Linux machine and I'm trying to find out what shell I am using.

When I run `echo $0`, I get `sh`.
`ps -p $$` has the same output.

However, as I understand it, `sh` is not a real shell, but only a symlink to a real shell such as `bash`, `dash`, `ksh`, etc.

So how can I find out the real shell behind `sh`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to see full symlink path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017500/how-to-see-full-symlink-path)

Comment: Indeed, `/bin/sh` is a simple symlink. Use the command from the question I marked as duplicate to see to which shell it links to. On my wsl, `readlink -f /bin/sh` returns `/bin/dash`

Comment: The point of `/bin/sh` is that you shouldn't *care* which shell it is. You write code that is defined by the POSIX specification, and whatever shell happens to be `/bin/sh` will execute it properly. Knowing which shell it is will just tempt you to use features specific to that shell, which defeats the purpose of using `/bin/sh` in the first place.

Comment: There is no guarantee that `sh` is a symlink. In fact, it very often isn't. Thus, this isn't a question about how to resolve a symlink. It's unclear what "[here][1]" is supposed to link to, though.

Comment: (I edited to remove the stillborn link.)

Comment: Sigh :-) Historically `/bin/sh` was the Bourne shell. A real shell. On some systems that is still true. On many systems it is likely an alias for the Bash, Zsh, Ksh, or other POSIX compatible shell. Also, @chepner's comment is extremely relevant. You **should not care** what implementation `sh` refers to as long as it conforms to the POSIX 1003.2 specification.

Answer (score 4):

The entire point of (POSIX) `sh` is that you should not need to know or care which precise implementation you are running. Simply assume that it conforms to [IEEE Std 1003.1™-2017](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/shell.html) aka POSIX.

There are some scenarios where you might need more detailed information.

- Older versions of Solaris shipped with a non-POSIX `sh` for a long time. You would find a POSIX-compatible `sh` in `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh`. Maybe use this binary if it's available; though these days, that old problem will have fixed itself (nobody in their right mind runs a Solaris which is *that* old).

  Similarly, of course, the original AT&T Bourne shell predates POSIX. Its modern descendant [Heirloom `sh`](https://heirloom.sourceforge.net/sh.html) is open source, though not necessarily trivial to build.

  If you need to support really old systems, probably enumerate your target platforms, and figure out how to test on each.

  If you need to support old monstrosities like HP-UX or AIX, perhaps you can find a vendor or client who can give you access to one of these systems for testing purposes.
- Busybox notoriously has some corner cases where it struggles with POSIX compliance. A dead giveaway is that `/bin/sh` and e.g. `/bin/ls` are identical; in Busybox, all utilities are implemented in one monolithic binary.

  In fact, (TIL) Busybox has two `sh` implementations, Ash and Hush. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62350/what-are-special-prompt-symbols-for-busyboxs-sh-support coincidentally shows how to know which one you have.
- When `sh` is really Bash, Dash, Ash, Ksh, Posh, etc, some of the details of their operation leak through. For example, Bash in POSIX mode still has support for many Bash extensions, where these are not expressly prohibited or dictated by POSIX.

A further complication is that many `sh` implementations have no detailed version or implementation information.

Again, if you require a specific behavior, it's probably best to simply test for that behavior.

Ultimately, being familiar with the shell implementation is only one component of writing a portable shell script. There are many variations in individual utilities (for example, the useful parts of modern `stat` are different across systems; the functionality specified by POSIX is crude and barren, and in particular unsuitable for producing machine-readable output). If you have a more modern but more narrow standard to code against, such as the Linux Standard Base, by all means do that.

Comment: "test behavior, not platform" needs to be re-discovered as a fundamental axiom.